# How to adjust the width of two divs to match screen size

Tags: css, html

http://demo.mythemeshop.com/ribbon/

Consider that template. I can change the size of my browser window, zoom into the webpage or view the webpage with a mobile. Both divs, left content `div` and right sidebar divs adjust automatically to the width. In a mobile interface only the content `div` is displayed and the right sidebar `div` comes after the content `div`.

I hope I am clear with my question.

I want to know how this is achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That template is based on twitter bootstrap.

Find [this](http://getbootstrap.com/) link..

Comment: This makes my job so much simpler.

Comment: glad it helped.. you can vote it as correct answer so that it will help others

Answer (score 1):

Find media max-width 720px in your CSS and replace with this

```
@media screen and (max-width:720px) { 
.secondary-navigation a {
    padding-top: 10px!important;
    padding-bottom: 10px!important;
}
.article { width: 99.4% }
#content_box {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px!important;
}
.sidebar.c-4-12 {
    width: 30%;
}
.f-widget { width: 44% }
.f-widget-2 { margin-right: 0 }
.ad-125 li { max-width: 45% }
.footer-widgets #s { width: 70% }
#comments { margin-right: 0 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are your problems, from http://demo.mythemeshop.com/ribbon/wp-content/themes/ribbon/style.css:

```
.sidebar.c-4-12 {
    max-width: 300px;
}

#tabber {
    max-width: 330px;
}
```

Remove both of those and the width of the sidebar posts will be the same as the width of the content posts.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, what you are seeing is two different responsive concepts. To really be able to understand either, you need to know that it is two entirely different concepts of mobile design.

If you put a div with 100% as the width, that div will be 100% the width of the screen. If you put 50% width, it will be 50% of the screen, always.

However, if the div mentioned above, is inside of another div that has a width of say... 1140px, then the div of 100% inherits 1140 width, unless the screen is smaller than the div. Then the 100% width would shrink in width to whatever is available to it.

Here are two common width layouts. 960 is reliable and older, 1140 is more modern. Read about CSS fixed width layouts. *Every new person asks what size should my column be and why...*

http://960.gs/

So I just described a responsive % layout. Now I will explain briefly the effect you described above where the sidebar disappears on mobile devices and appears. They are called media queries. You can google them to get a good understanding. You can have certain parts of your style sheet change if the screen size is different. When the screen is small, the media query changes the float:right and the width in the css style sheet.

This site is great to learn media queries etc...

Comment: http://www.1140px.com/
 This is another layout. It's wider than 960. I could not post more than two links because I don't have 10 reputation. lol